# Is there a Reactor operator for snapshot + streaming updates pattern

Tags: project-reactor

There is a common pattern in finance where a client can subscribe to a "book" of orders by retrieving a snapshot of the current book state and then an ongoing stream of order messages (add/delete/modify) which affect the book state.

To guarantee that no messages are missed one can first subscribe to the ongoing update stream, then retrieve the snapshot, and then apply all the update messages on top of the snapshot. In general some updates will be earlier than the snapshot and these can be made no-ops or discarded, and some later, but there are no gaps and you can end up with a valid and continuously updating view of the book.

I'd like to merge these two streams into one flux request using java reactor, but I can't find an operator or recipe that does what I want:

1. subscribe to a never-ending update flux and start buffering the messages
2. subscribe to a snapshot flux and emit all those messages until it completes
3. replay the buffered update messages; and
4. emit all subsequent update messages (never-ending)

Merge, concat, etc. don't quite seem to work. Any pointers to an operator or recipe to achieve this?

To clarify, the problem i'm concerned about is this (here Item has a id (a letter) and a state or value (a number)):

```
    Hot source: a=1, b=2,     a=3, b=4, b=5, b=6, ...
               ^snapshot:
               a=1, b=2, |
                                   ^update:
                                   b=4, b=5, b=6, ...

    mergeSequential yields merged stream: a=1, b=2, b=4, b=5, b=6, ...
```

So we miss a=3; it was published after the snapshot completes but before the update subscription was operative. We end up thinking that a's terminal state is a=1, when in fact it's a=3.

Perhaps it's unlikely since the snapshot and update are subscribed eagerly, but since the items are coming into the hot flux asynchronously and being emitted in a different scheduler/thread, it seems the scenario is possible.

To solve this I would like to subscribe first to updates, buffer them while I subscribe to the snapshot, and once the snapshot is complete emit the sapshot followed by the never-ending update. This is a lot like mergeSequential but the order of emitted items should reverse the order of subscription.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you solved it by now but here's a solution: you could pull this off by creating an eager hot source.

```
//You use a unicast sink
var buffer = Sinks.many().unicast().withBackpressureBuffer();

//subscribe eagerly to snaspshot source and publish on the buffer sink
//save subscription Disposable if you want to kill the subscription later
var subscription = getUpdateFlux().map(buffer::emitNext).subscribe();

//at this point you are already consuming from the updates so compose the end publisher for subscribtion
return getSnapshotMono().mergeWith(buffer.asFlux())
```

Mind you there are some potential drawbacks like the buffer running out of space and maybe there are other steps needed (like splitting the snapshot into individual updates for example) based on your case but this should not miss any of the updates.

Answer (score 0):

[`Flux.flatMapSequential`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMapSequential-java.util.function.Function-) will subscribe to all sourced Publishers at subscription, but will emit the items in order of their source Publisher. In this case, we can subscribe to both `Mono<Snapshot>` and `Flux<Update>` at the same time, but we will ensure that the Snapshot item is always emitted first.

To filter out Updates with timestamps, I use [`Flux.switchOnFirst`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#switchOnFirst-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to transform the flux once it emits its first element (the Snapshot), namely by extracting the Snapshot timestamp then filtering on timestamps greater or equal to it.

```java
public interface Item {
    Instant timestamp();
}

public record Snapshot(Instant timestamp) implements Item {}

public record Update(Instant timestamp) implements Item {}

public Flux<Item> getFlux() {
    Flux<Update> updateFlux = getUpdateFlux();
    Mono<Snapshot> snapshotMono = getSnapshotMono();

    return Flux.mergeSequential(snapshotMono, updateFlux)
            .switchOnFirst((firstSignal, flux) -> {
                if (firstSignal.hasValue()) {
                    Instant snapshotTimestamp = firstSignal.get().timestamp();
                    return flux.filter(item -> !item.timestamp().isBefore(snapshotTimestamp));
                }
                return flux; // no transformation on errors or completions
            });
}
```

Here I assumed both Update and Snapshot extend Item, but if there is no superclass to both, you can return a `Flux<Object>` instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion and sorry for the long delay. However I don't think your suggestion works. I've edited the original post to clarify what I'm concerned about if the order of subscription is snapshot the update - a missed value in the hot stream that leaves me with the wrong final value.